# Raspberry Pi provider for Vagrant?

Tags: raspberry-pi, vagrant

I'm currently evaluating Vagrant, and so far I really like what I've seen. As per default Vagrant uses Virtual Box as VM, but can also use other local or remote targets, as long as there's a provider for it, e.g. VMware or Amazon.

Now I'd like to use Vagrant to deploy a VM to a Raspberry Pi. Is this possible?

I know that in the end this means I need to run some kind of virtualization on the Pi (and it's a definitely reasonable question whether that's a good idea at all, but I'm curious).

Is this possible? If so, how?

*Please note that I first asked this on ServerFault, but the question does not fit there, as they don't see RasPis as "real" servers … hence I am re-asking the question here.*

Comment: ARM CPU (700 MHz ARM1176JZF-S core) + 512MB RAM, is Pi really capable of running guest OSes and Containers (LXC)???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible route would be to use Vagrant to manage the state of the image locally, and then [use qemu-img to convert the vmdk to an img file](http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/ch_converting.html) and [flash that to the SD card](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md).